# Codeception. Output variable while scenario is running

Tags: php, phpunit, codeception

Is it possible to log or output any user data while the scenario is running?
I know that the php code is executed two times at each run, how can I see a variable's value during the second step?

Comment: How the PHP code is executed 2 times?

Comment: "But you should keep in mind that Codeception executes each scenario two times: one for analysis and one for execution. So, any custom PHP code put in the file will be executed two times!". This is from tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    use Codeception\Extension\Logger;

    if ($scenario->running()) {
        Logger::log((string)$var);
    }
?>
```

please, do see [docs](http://codeception.com/docs/02-GettingStarted#Important-Notes)

and regarding seeing variable value, the preferable way is typecasting to string if it's a scalar data, accessing array index/key if it's an array, etc. but there is undocumented method $var->__value() which you can use for debugging, but should not rely on it in tests

Comment: I know it must be obvious, but can't figure it out. I get a FatalError `Class 'Logger' not found`

Comment: all vendors should be installed before using Codeception

Comment: Maybe this is too old. In newer versions of Codeception there is no such a thing as static Method log() in Logger class.

Answer (score 5):

```
codecept_debug($var);
```

And run codecept in "debug mode" to see it:

```
./vendor/bin/codecept run -d
```

If you want to make sure that your var is shown not only in debug mode:

```
$t = ob_get_clean(); // get current output buffer and stopping output buffering
var_dump($var); // show what we need
ob_start(); // start output buffering
echo($t); // restore output buffer
```

You can move this code out to external library.